# Suppress TeXworks PDF preview

Tags: texworks, viewers

Is there any way to suppress the PDF preview appearing? I really don't like the internal PDF viewer and I prefer using Acrobat. (I know that on Windows, Acrobat makes the `.pdf` file read-only, but I'm on linux and it behaves better here). It is annoying pop-up that I have to kill or so whenever I compile.

Comment: I miss few things: facing pages, anti-aliasing, countinuous page mode. Maybe some new version have it, but I have an old linux distro and miss the new updates.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the "Typesetting" tab of the preferences, you can double click the tool you use, say "pdfLaTeX" and there you can disable "View PDF after running".

I'm afraid you have to do it for all tools.

Comment: Thanks, I use only two of them so it's pretty fine for me!

Answer (score 20):

Opening the PDF viewer part of TeXworks is configured on a per-tool basis in the Typesetting preferences. So for example to prevent the viewer opening after typesetting using pdfLaTeX, I would need to untick the box in the following dialog
[image]

(Screenshot on Windows, but the same principal applies on Linux)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems that egreg made it 2 minutes faster! :-o

Comment: @tohecz: This would have been 3 minutes faster without the pretty picture! ;)

Comment: I know, but I didn't want to un-accept the first answer since it was what I really used... J.W. gets more upvotes, so it equalizes them ;)