# PDF Quality Issue in TeXworks Preview

Tags: texworks

## Update

I am very intrigued by the answer to this question: [Rendering issue in TeXworks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697539/rendering-issue-in-texworks). The answer suggests a potential solution involves replacing the miktex-texworks.exe file with a fresh version from GitHub. However, I'm struggling to follow the provided steps. Specifically, I can't seem to locate the updated binary on GitHub, and I'm also unable to find the miktex-texworks.exe file on my Windows system. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to find these two files.

## Main Content

### Edit: Not an issue with tikz-3dplot; solely an issue with the TeXworks previewer

I've got this super weird thing happening in TeXworks that's driving me up the wall. So, the quality of my PDFs in the preview is like, terrible, but when I actually check the PDF file, it's all good — clear and crisp.

Now, here's the real challenge: I need that preview to look sharp because I'm running a Python script that not only runs LaTeX but also visualizes it, apparently displaying the same thing as the preview. Any of you wizards out there got a clue on how to fix this?

This is what I'm getting in the preview:

[image]

This is what I'm getting in the pdf file:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,line join=bevel,tdplot_main_coords,%
fill opacity=.5]
\tdplotsetpolarplotrange{0}{360}{0}{360}
\tdplotsphericalsurfaceplot[parametricfill]{72}{36}%
{1+(1/5)*sin(6*\tdplottheta)*sin(5*\tdplotphi)}{black}{\tdplotphi}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{};}%
{\path[color=black,thick,->] (0,0,0)
-- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{};}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the log for those interested:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.11)  11 NOV 2023 09:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./bumpy_sphere.tex
(bumpy_sphere.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgfplots\pgfplots.sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.rev
ision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2021/05/15 v1.18.1 Data Visualization (1.18.1)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer\tikz.
sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgf.sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.st
y
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil
-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks18
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen143
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen144
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil
-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box51
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfrcs.
code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf\pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcore.
sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsys.
sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks19
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks20

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
libraryfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks21
))
\pgf@x=\dimen145
\pgf@y=\dimen146
\pgf@xa=\dimen147
\pgf@ya=\dimen148
\pgf@xb=\dimen149
\pgf@yb=\dimen150
\pgf@xc=\dimen151
\pgf@yc=\dimen152
\pgf@xd=\dimen153
\pgf@yd=\dimen154
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count193
\c@pgf@countb=\count194
\c@pgf@countc=\count195
\c@pgf@countd=\count196
\t@pgf@toka=\toks22
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks24
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count197

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgf.c
fg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
s-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
ssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count198
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count199
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer\pgfsy
sprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1374.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1375.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1376.
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
e.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code
.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.
code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparse
r.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen155
\pgfmath@count=\count266
\pgfmath@box=\box52
\pgfmath@toks=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks26
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks27
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunct
ions.integerarithmetics.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.
code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count267
))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfint.code.
tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen156
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen157
\pgf@picminy=\dimen158
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen159
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen160
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen161
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen162
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen163
\pgf@xx=\dimen164
\pgf@xy=\dimen165
\pgf@yx=\dimen166
\pgf@yy=\dimen167
\pgf@zx=\dimen168
\pgf@zy=\dimen169
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen170
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen171
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen172
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen173
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
escopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box53
\pgf@hbox=\box54
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box55
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count268
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
egraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen174
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
etransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen175
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen176
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen177
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
equick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
earrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen178
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen179
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count269
\pgf@shadingcount=\count270
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
eexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box56
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
elayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
etransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
epatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer\pgfcor
erdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
shapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box57
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
plot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfco
mp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen180
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen181
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/compatibility\pgfco
mp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgffor.st
y
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.s
ty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys
.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/pgf/math\pgfmath.sty
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code
.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.
code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen182
\pgffor@skip=\dimen183
\pgffor@stack=\toks28
\pgffor@toks=\toks29
))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z\tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibr
aryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count271
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen184
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen185
\tikz@lasty=\dimen186
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen187
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen188
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen189
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen190
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen191
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen192
\tikz@figbox=\box58
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box59
\tikz@tempbox=\box60
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box61
\tikztreelevel=\count272
\tikznumberofchildren=\count273
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count274
\tikz@fig@count=\count275

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
matrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count276
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count277
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count278
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count279

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.cod
e.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscore
.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks30
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks31
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks32
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen193
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count280
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count281

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgfplots
sysgeneric.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgfplot
slibrary.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompat
ib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibr
aryfpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary utilities for your pgf version...
\t@pgf@toka=\toks33
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks34
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks35

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompat
ib\pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
sutil.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructur
e\pgfplotsliststructure.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructur
e\pgfplotsliststructureext.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructur
e\pgfplotsarray.code.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count282
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructur
e\pgfplotsmatrix.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable\pgf
plotstableshared.code.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count283
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks36
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructur
e\pgfplotsdeque.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
sbinary.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
sbinary.data.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
sutil.verb.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\pgflibr
arypgfplots.surfshading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count284

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/sys\pgflibra
rypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
scolormap.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/util\pgfplot
scolor.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsstac
kedplots.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsplot
handlers.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmesh
plothandler.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotsmesh
plotimage.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.sca
ling.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotscoor
dprocessing.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.err
orbars.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.mar
kers.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplotstick
s.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots\pgfplots.pat
hs.code.tex)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/modules\pgfmodule
decorations.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen194
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen195
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen196
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen197
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen198
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count285
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen199
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen256
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box62
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorat
ions\pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorat
ions\pgflibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgfplots/libs\tikzlib
rarypgfplots.contourlua.code.tex)
\pgfplots@numplots=\count286
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen257
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen258
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen259
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen260
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen261
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen262
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibr
aryplotmarks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/tikz-3dplot\tikz-3dplot
.sty (C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibrary3d.code.tex
File: tikzlibrary3d.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tik
z/libraries\tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryarrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pgf/libraries\pgflibr
aryarrows.code.tex
File: pgflibraryarrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\arrowsize=\dimen263
)))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count287
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box63
)
No file bumpy_sphere.aux.
\openout1 = `bumpy_sphere.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count288
\scratchdimen=\dimen264
\scratchbox=\box64
\nofMPsegments=\count289
\nofMParguments=\count290
\everyMPshowfont=\toks37
\MPscratchCnt=\count291
\MPscratchDim=\dimen265
\MPnumerator=\count292
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count293
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks38
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

3dplot: processing 3d surface plot...
[1

{C:/Users/twill/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(bumpy_sphere.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 23438 strings out of 475248
 625469 string characters out of 5757812
 2421785 words of memory out of 5000000
 44645 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 99i,6n,103p,734b,881s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/twill/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bumpy_sphere.pdf (1 page, 34429 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I have been getting problem with previews more than a month now, with no solution so far. I posted a few days ago. Can you try an article class with pagecolor{blue} and see if you get a white line?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @YiannisLazarides. The problem persists when I set the page color to blue and use the article class - and yes, there is a white line. Interestingly, factory resetting my computer did not fix the issue. I'm sorry you're having trouble with this too.

Comment: I am actually surprised that only the two of us reporting the problem so far. My original question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700093/bug-in-texworks-viewer

Comment: A user facing a similar issue, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697539/rendering-issue-in-texworks, suggests a potential solution involves replacing the miktex-texworks.exe file with a fresh version from GitHub. However, I'm struggling to follow the provided steps. Specifically, I can't seem to locate the updated binary on GitHub, and I'm also unable to find the miktex-texworks.exe file on my Windows system. Would you be able to provide guidance on this matter, @YiannisLazarides?

Comment: If all else fails: Is your Windows system 10 or later, with the Linux subsystem installed? If so, you can install TeXlive there. Most distros (including Ubuntu) also have TeXworks, which is a separate download from texlive. You can install VNC (virtual network computing) into the Linux subsystem, and view it in Windows with a suitable VNC viewer. Essentially, one part of your computer is talking to itself, as if they were two computers. No boot change required. Works. Instructions are here and there on the Internet.

Comment: @Pseudonym123    The link to download is https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/releases/tag/release-0.6.8  The release comes in a zip folder. Unzip. Click on th executable, try on your .tex file. On mine the problem disappeared! I just made another shortcut. Left the old one as it was.

Comment: It works!!! What a relief! Thank you so much for assisting me with that @YiannisLazarides

Comment: Hmm, my python script is still displaying the old texworks preview, when it runs pdflatex... Any clue as to how I can configure pdflatex to generate the preview of the new texworks executable?

Comment: @Pseudonym123 In TeXworks go to Help->Settings and Resources->About TexWorks, shows the folder where TeXworks(old) was located. To permanently do the change, save the folder somewhere to be safe then replace with the new. Or check your python scrpt to point to the new location

Comment: Interesting, that didn't solve the issue. I found a workaround though by forcing it to display the pdf instead of the preview. Thanks again for all your effort though. I'm really happy that this problem has been resolved - for both of us.

Comment: To force the display of the pdf instead of the preview, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44409/166831